# What is the probability that three heads occur before three tails?

Tags: probability

A biased coin has probability p
of showing heads. We toss the coin repeatedly until three heads or three tails occur in row. What is the probability that three heads occur before three tails?

I know how to solve this for two heads and two tails.

$$
P(A) =  p^2 + pq \cdot P(A|HT) + pq \cdot P(A|TH) 
$$

Then, it is easy to relate $$ P(A∣HT)=p \cdot P(A∣TH) $$ and $$P(A∣TH)=p+qP(A∣HT) $$

And find solution. However for three we will have equation like this:

$$
P(A) = p^3 + p^2q \cdot P(A|HHT) + p^2q \cdot P(A|HTH) + p^2q \cdot P(A|THH) + q^2p \cdot P(A|HTT)  + q^2p \cdot P(A|THT) + q^2p \cdot P(A|TTH) 
$$
How can we relate these conditional probabilities?
The link for case with 2 tosses:
[What is the probability that two heads occur before two tails?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147596/what-is-the-probability-that-two-heads-occur-before-two-tails)

Comment: Usual methodology should work...there are very few states here.  All we care about is the running string, so every state (other than START and END) can be described as either $T^i$ or $H^i$ for $i=1,2$.  So...just four non-trivial states.  Write down and solve the system of linear equations the transitions imply.

Comment: @lulu I can relate $ P(A|HHT) = p \cdot P(A|HTH) = p^2 \cdot P(A|THH) $ and $ P(A|TTH) = q \cdot P(A|THT) = q^2 \cdot P(A|HTT) $. Is it correct that $ P(A|TTH) = p + q \cdot P(A|THH) $

Comment: Not sure I see those relations.  To me, the state $HHT$ is just the state $T$...what difference does the $HH$ make?  If I am in the state $T$ then I can only go to $TT$ or to $H$.  Thus $P_{T}=p\times P_H+q\times P_{T^2}$  (where, for a state $S$, $P_S$ denotes the probability of winning if I start in $S$).

Comment: Can you see the way I am generating equations?  Let $\psi$ denote the answer you seek.  Then, given the possible results of the first toss, we see that $\psi=p\times P_H +q\times P_T$ and so on (sticking with the notation of my last comment).

Comment: Yes, I see it. But how we would relate start and end then?

Comment: Well, you just have four equations to solve to compute $P_H, P_T, P_{TT}, P_{HH}$.  Since $HH$ can go to WIN or to $T$ we see that $P_{HH}=p\times 1 + q\times P_T$...that's how the END states come into it.

Comment: As a warm up, solve the $HH$ vs $TT$ problem this way.  Now there are only two non-trivial states.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ denote the probability of a head or a tail followed by head & no prevoius throw had three consecutive heads or tails.

Let $B$ denote the probability of two heads or a tail followed by two heads & no prevoius throw had three consecutive heads or tails.

Make similar definitions for $C$ ending with a singleton tail & $D$ ending with two tails. These quantities satisfy the following equations 
\begin{eqnarray*}
A&=&p+p(C+D) \\
B&=&pA \\
C&=&q+q(A+B) \\
D&=&qC 
\end{eqnarray*}
After a little algebra we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
A= \frac{p(1+q+q^2)}{1-pq(1+p)(1+q)}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So the probability of three heads occuring before three tails is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\color{red}{\frac{p^3(1+q+q^2)}{1-pq(1+p)(1+q)}}.
\end{eqnarray*}